# How check if User still Online ASP MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, session, cookies, session-cookies

I write Chat online
U write all by myself
so i wrote Login, and Set AuthCookie and i did authentication

Now i need check all N-time which users online.

I have Table in DataBase named Users_Online (Id, User_Id)
When I login (or when i come to chat page(if I have Auth cookie) - i set row in table Users_online.

But How i can remove row when i go out (Not sing out, just close tab/browser)???
I try use Session_OnStart/Session_OnEnd in Global.asax - but last (Session_OnEnd) - not work correct.

So Please help me guys.

Comment: There's no way you can detect if a user just closes his browser's window. You could consider them disconnected after some inactivity period, for instance.

Comment: ok. can you giva a code, example, or link how do it? Thank you btw for fast answer

Comment: Not really, there are too many ways to do it. Google for ASP.NET MVC inactivity session close for instance.

Comment: Ok. thank you. If someone can write here example - it be helpful. Thanks to all

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I resolve my problem (i hope) ))
If someone need a example:

In Global.asax file you will need have 2 methods:

```
public void Session_OnStart()
{
    //here you do something
}
public void Session_OnEnd()
{
   //your logic 
}
```

And in Web.Config you need write:

```
 <sessionState mode="InProc" cookieless="false" timeout="##Here you write timeout for session"></sessionState>
```

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it right try use SignalR ([signalr.net](http://signalr.net))

Session_OnEnd will not trigger when somebody close the browser :)

Comment: Yeah - but if you do 2-3 mins for session timeout - you can check if user still online. And yeah - SignalR - best and right way - but task was Not use something - only Webservices/WebAPI - Its just task from studying

Comment: If you do 2-3min for session timeout, users will have to login after 2-3min idle time. This solution is ok to pass a course.

Comment: I set cookie for 2 days - and after  2-3min idle time when users do something - my Auth filter just set new session